# Calculate the computation cost

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, lu-decomposition

Let $f(n)$ be the cost of computation of the LU analysis of a mtarix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and let $g(n)$ nbe the cost of the computation of the solution of a linear system, given the LU analysis of $A$.

I want to calculate the computation cost of $A^{-3}c$, where $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

$$$$

I have done the following:

We have that $A=LU$ where $L$ is a lower and $U$ an upper triangular matrix, correct?

Let $y$ be the solution, i.e. $$A^{-3}c=y \Rightarrow A^3y=c \Rightarrow LULULUy = c$$

We hve to solve $6$ linear systems: $$L\left (U\left (L\left (U\left (L\left (Uy\right ) \right ) \right ) \right ) \right ) = c$$

Therefore, we apply once the LU decomposition of $A$ and so we have the cost $f(n)$ and we solve $6$ times a linear system and so we get additional the cost $6g(n)$.

So, in total we have the cost $f(n)+6g(n)$.

$$$$

Is that correct?

Comment: No, $f(n)+3g(n)$.

Comment: Ah ok, why? @YvesDaoust

Comment: Because $A^{-3}$.

Comment: So, is it as follows? $$$$ We apply the the LU analysis of $A$ and so we have the cost $f(n)$ so far. Then let $y$ be the solution, $y:=A^{-3}c \Rightarrow A^3y=c$. It is given that $g(n)$ is the cost of the calculation of the solution of a linear system and since we have three linear systems: $A\left (A\left (Ay\right )\right )=c$ we have the cost $3g(n)$. $$$$ Is everything correct? @YvesDaoust

Comment: You get it now.